# Is there any cognitive architecture applications?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example:

Is there any applications using cram-highlevel or other cognitive architecture available launch by roslaunch on simulations like gazebo?

I think applications will be great to start with understanding cognitive architectures.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30520/is-there-any-cognitive-architecture-applications?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears there are not examples.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1